# Set Ruby variable if it is not already defined

Tags: ruby, variables, set

In Ruby, how do you set a variable to a certain value if it is not already defined, and leave the current value if it is already defined?

Comment: by "defined", do you mean "it exists in the current scope" or, "it is not == nil" ?

Comment: @zetetic: "it exists in the current scope"

Answer (score 56, accepted):

While `x ||= value` is a way to say "if x contains a falsey value, including nil (which is implicit in this construct *if* x is not defined because it appears on the left hand side of the assignment), assign value to x", it does just that.

It is *roughly* equivalent to the following. (However, `x ||= value` will not throw a `NameError` like this code *may* and it will always assign a value to `x` as this code does not -- the point is to see `x ||= value` works the same for *any* falsey value in x, including the "default" `nil` value):

```
if !x
  x = value
end
```

To see if the variable has *truly* not been assigned a value, use the `defined?` method:

```
>> defined? z
=> nil                                                                  
>> z = nil                                                              
=> nil                                                                  
>> defined? z                                                           
=> "local-variable"                                                     
>> defined? @z                                                          
=> nil                                                                  
>> @z = nil                                                             
=> nil                                                                  
>> defined? @z                                                          
=> "instance-variable"
```

**However, in *almost every case*, using `defined?` is code smell.** Be careful with power. Do the sensible thing: give variables values before trying to use them :)

Happy coding.

Comment: What is it about `||=` that makes it not throw a `NameError` if the variable is not defined? Is that built into the operator? Are there other operators that work that way?

Comment: @jrdioko "Magic" ;) Actually, it has to do with `x` appearing on the Left Hand Side of the assignment -- it doesn't matter if a value has not been assigned yet (it will "default" to `nil`). For instance, `z = z.nil? # => true` even when `z` was not currently defined.

Comment: @pst I guess the "defined?" method is just a more elegant alternative than fishing out the "NameError: undefined local variable or method" So the real answer is that you will know if you haven't already defined a variable when your program errors out.

Comment: yeah, this is much better if you are setting variables as true/false

Comment: @Dmitri @Codeglot Indeed. The most elegant way is to write code *that can't cause* a `NameError`! (and verified as such with good test coverage) ;-)

Comment: Why is using `defined?` code smell? Could you please explain that part.

Comment: @Hengjie Because there should be no question of *if* a `variable` has been set (which implies `defined?` is truthy) in code. Of course, there are exceptions (with `@variable`, perhaps?) .. but if you're at such a special scenario then you'll know it, and why it's okay. If you don't know why it's okay, then it's not :)

Comment: @Hengjie That is, just like `eval`, `defined?` is "usually not the right tool": when it appears the usage must be questioned. If the particular usage cannot be suitably defended then it should be removed.

Comment: Code smell? More like removing code fragility, just because **you** don't think a situation couldn't occur doesn't mean that it could never happen. Future development may somehow accidentally make this variable undefined (mistaken spelling in the declaration, for example). Checking if a variable is defined will catch such a bug, and make it easy to find. However, without the check, the problem might not be as quick to solve.

Answer (score 33):

```
@variable ||= "set value if not set"
```

So `false` variables will get overridden

```
> @test = true 
 => true 
> @test ||= "test"
 => true 
> @test 
 => nil 
> @test ||= "test"
 => "test" 
> @test = false 
 => false 
> @test ||= "test"
 => "test"
```

Comment: It could be set to a falsey-value, however. As such, this is only approximately correct.

Comment: Can you clarify how that works (and how false values are handled)?

Comment: `> @test` should be `> @test = nil`

Comment: TIL: This does not work with hash values like `bodyParams['owner'] ||= ''` if there is no key called `'owner'`. It will give you an `IndexError`. For that, check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39549523/1025430

Answer (score 8):

As you didn't specify what kind of variable:

```
v = v
v ||= 1
```

Don't recommend doing this with local variables though.

**Edit:** In fact v=v is not needed

Comment: It could be set to a falsey-value, however. As such, this is only approximately correct.

Comment: irb(main):007:0> v = v
    => nil // 
    irb(main):008:0> v.class
    => NilClass // so same as initializing it as v = nil

Comment: @Dmitri No, it is not the same, if v has a value, it won't change. That is the point.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is not defined (declared?) it doesn't exist, and if it is declared then you know how you initialized it, right?

Usually, if I just need a variable whose use I don't yet know---that I know will *never* use as a Boolean---I  initialize it by setting its value to nil.  Then you can test if it has been changed later quite easily

```
x = nil


some code


if x do 
[code that will only run if x has changed]
end
```

that's all.

Comment: It could be set to a falsey-value, however. As such, this is only approximately correct.

Comment: that is quite true, @pst I don't use this technique if the expected value is a Boolean.