# How to get a default value with hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get a default value whilst using hashes in ruby.  Looking up the documentation you use a fetch method.  So if a hash is not entered then it defaults to a value.  This is my code.

```
def input_students
  puts "Please enter the names and hobbies of the students plus country of    birth"
  puts "To finish, just hit return three times"

  #create the empty array
  students = []
  hobbies = []
  country = []
  cohort = []

  # Get the first name
  name = gets.chomp
  hobbies = gets.chomp
  country = gets.chomp
  cohort = gets.chomp

  while !name.empty? && !hobbies.empty? && !country.empty? && cohort.fetch(:cohort, january) do #This is to do with entering twice
    students << {name: name, hobbies: hobbies, country: country, cohort: cohort} #import part of the code.
    puts "Now we have #{students.count} students"

    # get another name from the user
    name = gets.chomp
    hobbies = gets.chomp
    country = gets.chomp
    cohort = gets.chomp
  end
  students
end
```

Comment: The downvote was likely because you have not stated your question. You need to edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: Consider waiting longer (at least a couple of hours, perhaps) before selecting an answer. Quick selections may discourage other answers and short-circuits those still working on answers. There's no rush. You still need to edit your question, as many members may read your question in future (and also to stem more downvoting).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You just need to give `fetch` a default it can handle. It doesn't know what to do with `january` as you haven't declared any variable with that name. If you want to set the default value to the string `"january"`, then you just need to quote it like this:

```
cohort.fetch(:cohort, "january")
```

There are some decent examples in the [documentation for `fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch).

Also, `cohort` isn't a `Hash`, it's a `String` since `gets.chomp` returns a `String`. `fetch` is for "fetching" values from a `Hash`. The way you're using it should be throwing an error similar to: `undefined method 'fetch' for "whatever text you entered":String`.

Finally, since you're using it in a conditional, the result of your call to `fetch` is being evaluated for its truthiness. If you're setting a default, it will always be evaluated as `true`.

If you just want to set a default for `cohort` if it's empty, you can just do something like this:

```
cohort = gets.chomp
cohort = "january" if cohort.empty?
while !name.empty? && !hobbies.empty? && !country.empty?
  students << {
    name: name,
    hobbies: hobbies,
    country: country,
    cohort: cohort
  }
  ... # do more stuff
```

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: So I was nearly there. Just had to make january a string.

Comment: Now I am getting this error `coderunner.rb:16:in `input_students': undefined method `fetch' for "":String (NoMethodError)` .

Comment: See my expanded answer above.

Comment: So what would be the best approach for this if I can't use fetch.

Comment: Added another example

Comment: That's fantastic dinjas and Cary Swoveland .  This has been really helpful.

Comment: You can also write `until name.empty? || hobbies.empty? || country.empty?`.

Answer (score 23):

You have several options. @dinjas mentions one, likely the one you want to use. Suppose your hash is

```
h = { :a=>1 }
```

Then

```
h[:a] #=> 1
h[:b] #=> nil
```

Let's say the default is `4`. Then as dinjas suggests, you can write

```
h.fetch(:a, 4) #=> 1
h.fetch(:b, 4) #=> 4
```

But other options are

```
h.fetch(:a) rescue 4 #=> 1
h.fetch(:b) rescue 4 #=> 4
```

or

```
h[:a] || 4 #=> 1
h[:b] || 4 #=> 4
```

You could also build the default into the hash itself, by using [Hash#default=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-default-3D):

```
h.default = 4
h[:a] #=> 1
h[:b] #=> 4
```

or by defining the hash like so:

```
g = Hash.new(4).merge(h)
g[:a] #=> 1
g[:b] #=> 4
```

See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new).

Comment: Also one might use [`Hash#default_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D) to return values depending on some conditions.

Comment: @mudasobwa, good point. Readers, a common example is `h.default_proc = ->(h,k) { h[k] = [] }`, so if one writes `h[k] << 3` and `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` is set equal to an empty array and then `3` is appended to that array. That can also be written `h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }.merge(<your hash>)`.