# What is this in Ruby? ||=

Tags: ruby

While programming routes in Sinatra, I came across code listed as this:

```
before do
  session[:lists] ||= []
end
```

What is this operation doing `||= []`?

Comment: Huh, googling "ruby ||=" actually doesn't give anything useful, from what I could see. Try googling "ruby or equals" instead.

Comment: Yes, this has a zillion answers on SO already.

Comment: The Rails tag should be removed as this is a pure-Ruby question.

Comment: Symbolhound is better for this sort of thing: http://symbolhound.com/?q=ruby+%7C%7C%3D

Comment: Questions like this aren't bad to ask but they do suggest you don't have an adequate Ruby reference to work from.

Answer (score 2):

> x ||= value is a way to say "if x contains a falsey value, including
>   nil, assign value to x"

That's setting `session[:lists]` equal to `[]` if `session[:lists]` is falsey.

Related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6671466/4722305.

Answer (score 1):

It sets `[]` to `session[:lists]` when it's `nil` or `falsy`

Read more [here](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html)

;)